# Python: iterables & generators to replace my while true loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Let's start by my question: can you write a better code than the one below?

```
FRAME_DELIMITER = b'\x0a\x0b\x0c\x0d'
def get_data():
    f = bytearray();

    # detect frame delimiter
    while True:
        f += read_byte()
        if f[-4:] == FRAME_DELIMITER:
            start = len(f)-2
            break

    # read data until next frame delimiter
    while True:
        f += self._read_byte()
        if f[-4:] == FRAME_DELIMITER:
            return f[start:-2]
```

In few words, this code is reading a data flow and return an entire frame. Each frame is delimited by 0x0a 0x0b 0x0c.The read_byte function reads one byte on the data flow (maybe it could be convenient to retrieve a buffer of x bytes).

I had a look to Python documentation to try writing this code in a more pythonic way (and better performance ?).

I came to generators and iterators.

We could imagine to create a generator like this one:

```
def my_generator(self):
        while True:
            yield self._read_byte()
```

and play around with list comprehension and itertools like this one:

```
f = b''.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c != b'\x03', self.my_generator()))
```

But in fact I'm stuck because I need to check a delimiter pattern and not only one character.
Could you help in giving me the right direction ... Or maybe my code above is just what I need ?!

Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question _"can you write a better code than the one below?"_: yes, I can write better code than this ;). To ask a counter-question: are you having some problem with what you wrote? What is the problem?

Comment: No problem with the code I wrote. Simply looking for a more modern, pythonic way and if I can get better execution performance.

Comment: Just edited the question above to correct the mistake about pattern's length (4 bytes). The read_byte function is returning one byte (I can also decide to read n bytes).

Comment: That kind of question would be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It is actually off-topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

It's not practical to perform the test you're going for without *some* state, but you can hide the state in your generator!

You could make your generator read the frame itself, assuming the delimiter is a constant value (or you pass in the required delimiter). A `collections.deque` can allow it to easily preserve state only for the last four characters, so it's not just hiding large data storage in state:

```
def read_until_delimiter(self):
    # Note: If FRAME_DELIMITER is bytes, and _read_byte returns len 1 bytes objects
    # rather than ints, you'll need to tweak the definition of frame_as_deque to make it store bytes
    frame_as_deque = collections.deque(FRAME_DELIMITER)
    window = collections.deque(maxlen=len(FRAME_DELIMITER))

    while window != frame_as_deque:
        byte = self._read_byte()
        yield byte
        window.append(byte)  # Automatically ages off bytes to keep constant length after filling
```

Now your caller can just do:

```
f = bytearray(self.read_until_delimiter())
# Or bytearray().join(self.read_until_delimiter()) if reading bytes objects, not ints
start = len(f) - 2
```

Note: I defined the `maxlen` in terms of the length of `FRAME_DELIMITER`; your end of delimiter would almost never pass, because you sliced off the last *four* bytes, and compared them to a constant containing only *three* bytes.

Comment: Not really necessary, but while I'm here: The first two lines of the body of my while loop could combine to `yield (byte := self._read_byte())` on Python 3.8+, thanks to [PEP 572's](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) "walrus operator" (assignment as an expression). Not really necessary here, but fun to play with.

Comment: Also, a side-note: If you don't actually *need* `bytearray`, it may be more efficient to just use `bytes` once you're populating it in two bulk actions. If you're reading `bytes` objects from `_read_byte`, the rejoin at the end can use `b''.join` instead of `bytearray().join`. `bytearray` makes sense with individual repeated `append`s (to avoid Schlemiel the Painter algorithms), but for a couple of bulk actions, the overhead of `bytearray` (more fragmented memory, overallocation, possibly undesirable mutability) can be avoided.

Comment: Many thanks @ShadowRanger for your proposal. regarding your note, totally agree, it was my mistake when preparing the question. The pattern is 4 bytes long. I tested your code but the behaviour is not as expected. let's imagine I read this on my data flow is `ata abcd data abcd data abcd dat, I will get 'ata' with your proposal. I need to retrive a full 'data'. Do you see what I mean? Any way, usage of collections seems a good orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I think by saying a better code Is code that don't **slice** a the concatenated `bytes` sequence instead a smart `generator`, and use only one while loop:

```py
# just to simulate your method
data = b'AA\x0a\x0b\x0cBBqfdqsfqsfqsvcwccvxcvvqsfq\x0a\x0b\x0cqsdfqs'
index = -1
def get_bytes():
    # you used two method
    # return read_byte() if count == 2 else self._read_byte()
    global index
    index += 1
    return data[index:index + 1]


FRAME_DELIMITER = b'\x0a\x0b\x0c'
def get_data():
    def update_last_delimiter(v):
        """ update the delemeter with the last readed element"""
        nonlocal last_four_byte
        if len(last_four_byte) < len(FRAME_DELIMITER):
            last_four_byte += v
        else:
            last_four_byte = last_four_byte[1:] + v

    count = 2
    last_four_byte = b''
    while True:
        # because you have two method to extract bytes
        # replace get_bytes() by (read_byte() if count == 2 else self._read_byte())
        update_last_delimiter(get_bytes())

        # only yields items when the first DELIMITER IS FOUND
        if count < 2:
            yield last_four_byte[1:2]

        if last_four_byte == FRAME_DELIMITER:
            count -= 1
            if not count:
                break
            else:
                # when first DELIMITER is found we should yield the [-2] element
                yield last_four_byte[1:2]


print(b''.join(get_data()))
# b'\x0b\x0cBBqfdqsfqsfqsvcwccvxcvvqsfq\n\x0b'
```

The key here is to keep track of the last `DELIMITER` bytes